# Can you use JIRA's SOAP API in a VB.NET desktop application?

Tags: vb.net, soap, jira

I tried using JIRA's REST API but the function that I needed wasn't there and found it at JIRA's SOAP API. A newbie like me wants to know if you can use JIRA's SOAP API in a VB.NET desktop application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. The point of a SOAP service is to allow access to the data and functionality of application from another application regardless of the language it is written in. All you need is something in your program that understands how to talk to and work with a SOAP service.

I have no doubt that a VB.NET application can talk to a SOAP service without issue, but I am not a .NET programmer so I can not provide any specific guidance on how to do it.

What you will want to search for is "Consuming SOAP services with VB.NET". I did that myself and came up with some god looking tutorials.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/vbwebservice.aspx
http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/SrinivasSampath/WebServiceusingSOAPToolkit11242005002126AM/WebServiceusingSOAPToolkit.aspx
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/LVBE_L6_3.htm

Like I said, I think everything you need will be built into the .NET framework. I don't think you will need to download anything additional or include extra libraries.

Comment: So SOAP is something like REST? In REST you use URI to access and manipulate data but what does SOAP use? Do I need to download anything to use JIRA's SOAP API? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: SOAP is similar to REST in that they are both web services that you access via HTTP. They are very different in how you work with the data.   The differences are much more than I can get into in a short comment, but in my experience, the big difference between the two has simply been JSON (REST) vs XML (SOAP). Though XML can also be used with RESTful services, I find it to be less often. SOAP is always XML. As for whether or not you need to download anything, I will edit my answer to answer that.

Comment: Jason is correct, you can absolutely access a SOAP service from with .NET. Although I'm a C# programmer, I have actually written a desktop application and serveral libraries that integrate with JIRA communicating to both the REST and SOAP APIs.